# Applying an onclick event to an element that doesn't exist on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener

I have styled a list to look like a select box and I want to fire a function when the user clicks an element in the list however the element is loaded via `AJAX` and hence isn't there when the page loads and I can't bind an `onclick` event to it `onDomReady`.

If I had it as a normal select list I could just tag on an `onChange` event to the `<select>` field, but I obviously can't do that in my case.

My HTML:

```
<div id="main_category_field" class="fields">
    <div class="cat_list">
        <ul>
            <li class=""><a rel="1866" href="#1866">Sports Cards &gt;</a></li>
            <li class=""><a rel="1867" href="#1867">Gaming Cards &gt;</a></li>
            <li class=""><a rel="1868" href="#1868">Non-Sport Cards &gt;</a></li>
            <li class=""><a rel="1869" href="#1869">Supplies &amp; Storage &gt;</a></li>
            <li class=""><a rel="1940" href="#1940">Video Games </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="contentClear"></div>
</div>
```

How can I run a function whenever the user clicks any of these options? Also would be great if you could also advise how to pass the respective value of the `rel` back when they click an option.

Using jQuery so options in that would be preferred.

**Edit:** Meant to say that the main element `main_category_field` is a static element. The elements inside are loaded via AJAX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to delegate your elements to static parent , if the element is added dynamically using `on()`
try this

```
  $(document).on('click','li a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var rel = this.rel;
     //or using attr()
    var rel=$(this).attr('rel'); 
     alert(rel);  
  });
```

however delegating it to its closest static parent(present at a time of insertion) is better than document itself.. so if you are adding the list inside `main_category_field` div.. then you can use

```
    $('#main_category_field').on('click','li a',function(e){     
         //same stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method via the `main_category_field` element :)

Comment: Can someone give how you could write the `.on('click','li' a'` part in pure JavaScript? I've never seen that trick of adding on 'li a' like that for JQuery even, very neat. But I am making a tool in JavaScript where this trick would be very useful as I am having the same problem as OP with dynamically adding select options.

Comment: hmm, yes but it will not be as easy as using `on` jquery event since you have to keep event bubbling and traversing in mind to use event delegation in pure javascript. Here is a good blog to get started with http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 6):

The key word is `event delegation`. If you want to assign event handlers to dynamically added elements for which you know their "future" selectors, you should use the `.on()` method on an (already existing) parent element of those dynamic elements.

The second parameter to `.on()` is then the selector of the dynamically added elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.cat_list li a', function(e) {
   alert(this.rel);   // show the "rel" attribute of the clicked a element
   e.preventDefault();  // to prevent the default action of anchor elements
});
```

Comment: upvote for explanation using `.on()` function for dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on` for listen dynamically created dom elements as follows

```
$(document).on('click','div.cat_list ul li a',function(){
     var rel=$(this).attr('rel');//to get value of rel attribute
     alert(rel);   
     //other operations
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To bind an event handler to an element that does not yet exist on the page use `on`.

```
$(document).on("click", "#main_category_field", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var rel = e.target.rel;
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/82bAb/